# How to detect or prevent built-in browser functions from being replaced?

Tags: javascript, security, dom, websecurity

I noticed today that I can replace a sensitive built-in JS function like this:

```
async function _hackedEncrypt(algorithm, key, data) {
   console.log('hacked you!');
}

const subtle = global.crypto.subtle; // Assign to get around "read-only" error.
subtle.encrypt = _hackedEncrypt;

global.crypto.subtle.encrypt(); // 'Hacked you!' appears in console.
```

Yikes!

This exploit is so simple. Any of the thousands of dependencies (direct and transitive) in my web app could make this function reassignment. Note that my question isn't specific to Web Crypto - it's just one of the more dangerous targets for an attacker.

How can I either detect that the function has been reassigned or guarantee that I'm always calling the original browser implementation of it?

Comment: Running one virus compromises your entire system. Don't have thousands of dependencies.

Comment: An empty `create-react-app` comes with 1380 dependencies before you add one line of code to it. So with my chosen platform, a very popular one, I can't take your advice.

Comment: I am writing react, i've never used `create-react-app`. `react` itself (since a recent commit) will have zero dependencies, `react-dom` still has two.

Comment: Your point has merit. I am still looking for a solution that doesn't depend on trusting my direct and transitive dependencies to not expose me to this exploit.

Comment: Especially with node, e.g. what you run in `create-react-app`, you are executing code, which has permissions to read/write/execute on your drive. It can do basically anything, and is almost never sandboxed in any way. There are plenty of examples, where this went wrong, [here is a recent one that comes to mind](https://snyk.io/blog/peacenotwar-malicious-npm-node-ipc-package-vulnerability/), note how recent, and how many were affected.

Comment: What you're referring to is a supply chain attack. If you have a compromised dependency, it can siphon users credit cards etc. without replacing built-in JS functions, by just registering callbacks. There are [dedicated security products for protecting against supply chain attacks](https://cybersecurity-excellence-awards.com/candidate-category/security-product-awards-category/client-side-security/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a subset of a broader class of attacks: [Supply Chain Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_chain_attack).

The basic idea is that I create a JS library that is useful and trivial, over time a ton of projects depend on it, then I insert a back door, next time they upgrade they're dependencies - I have access to their users' browsers.
I can then steal passwords, credit card info, PII, etc. - basically digital skimming.
[Magecart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_skimming#Magecart) is probably being the best known attack in the JS space. Probably the best known one in general is the [Solarwinds attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SolarWinds#2019%E2%80%932020_supply_chain_attacks).

One solution is to roll your own. That is pretty much hopeless, because even though you might know what APIs you use, you don't know what your dependencies use, and how that changes.

Another solution is [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), which controls outgoing requests: a skimmer might have been able to put their code in your app, but they can't do anything useful if your content security policy doesn't let it issue requests to unknown hosts.

There are also commercial solution. I'm aware of:

- [PageDefender](https://www.perimeterx.com/products/page-defender/)
- [Client-Side Protection](https://www.imperva.com/products/client-side-protection/) (AFAICT uses Content Security Policy under the hood)
- [Page Integrity Manager](https://www.akamai.com/products/page-integrity-manager)
- [Client-Side Defense](https://www.f5.com/cloud/products/client-side-defense)

Answer (score 0):

In my `index.js`, I import this module ahead of any other modules. It must be the first import so that other dependencies don't get a chance to replace a function before I can set a reference to the original.

```
const originalEncrypt = global.crypto.subtle.encrypt;
// Any number of functions worth protecting can be added here
// and also added to the check in wereFunctionsReplaced().

function wereFunctionsReplaced() {
  return global.crypto.subtle.encrypt !== originalEncrypt;
}
```

...and then I call `wereFunctionsReplaced()` ahead of the function call I'm worried about:

```
if (wereFunctionsReplaced()) throw Error('Everybody run to the panic room!');
global.crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, data);
```

Of course, I could also wrap the protected functions like:

```
function safeEncrypt(algorithm, key, data) {
  if (wereFunctionsReplaced()) throw Error('Everybody run to the panic room!');
  return global.crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, data);
}
```

In some cases, it would be more convenient to store the built-in function to a variable and call the function directly from the variable rather than from `global.*`. But for `crypto.subtle.encrypt` it will throw a "Bad invocation" error in Chrome. And thinking harder about it, many subtle, unexpected behaviors could be caused by calling the built-in functions outside their expected location in the global hierarchy.

This is a self-answer for posterity. But I would love to hear better solutions than this one. Criticism on any faults this solution may have is welcome as well.

Comment: Con: The `wereFunctionsReplaced()` function can itself be replaced. It is much less likely to be targeted in an attack launched from a 3rd-party dependency, however.

Comment: If you want security by obscurity, where you differ from the norm far enough, so non-adapted malware is likely to stumble on your code, you may want to look into [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), and the [`configurable`/`writable` attributes of property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Note again, that i do not believe anything will protect you against malware adapted to your case - there is always some loophole to abuse.

Comment: Don't just check whether or not the function got replaced - just make it immutable before any foreign JS code gets executed. As @ASDFGerte has mentioned, use the `configurable` and `writable` attributes of those functions and set them both to `false`, and the properties cannot be tampered with any more. All you need is a JS provided by **you** that gets executed before anything else and locks any critical functions.